# Could particle wave duality be caused by gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, wave-particle-duality

We know that light (and other particles) displays particle wave duality, or the ability to be a particle and a wave at the same time. After that it becomes confusing. We also know that gravity is a sort of indentation in the space time continuum. Finally, we know that light has a gravitational field. So could particle wave duality be caused by a particle, let's say light, traveling through space-time, and creating a wave with its gravitational field? I have tried to research this question but I haven't gotten any kind of consistent results. I understand that this might be a dumb question but I'm no physicist.

Comment: Hi Tub. A [basic search of this site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=wave+particle+duality) would have found you detailed explanations of how wave particle duality arises. It has nothing to do with gravity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Light is made from a field, not from particles. That field has field quanta called photons, which are NOT the same thing as particles. As for "wave particle duality"... the sooner you file that in the same drawer as the phlogiston and the luminiferous aether, the sooner you can move on with learning 21st century science.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer requires a background in physics, to understand that measurements have told us that there are four interactions, (strong, weak, electromagnetic, gravitational) and in order of strength gravity is the weakest of all and will be the last to play any measurable role and is undetectable for elementary particles .

The wave property of particles appears in [cumulative  probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles), and it is not a mass or energy wave. Understanding requires studying physics and [quantum mechanics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quacon.html) in particular.